# What is the integral of $e^{x\cos\theta + y\cos\theta}$

Tags: integration, special-functions, bessel-functions

Knowing that $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{x\cos \theta } d\theta = 2\pi I_0(x)$$ where $I_0$ is the [modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I.CE.B1_.2C_K.CE.B1). Is there a way/trick to find an analytical expression for
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{x\cos \theta + y\cos \theta} d\theta.$$

Comment: $x\cos\theta+y\cos\theta=(x+y)\cos\theta$, so are you sure you meant this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why would this not be
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{x\cos t + y \cos t} dt 
= \int_0^{2\pi} e^{(x+y)\cos t} dt 
= 2\pi I_0(x+y)?
$$

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct

Comment: Great, many thanks

Comment: This gets 7 votes?  I'm working too hard, apparently.